# Setting CSS class attribute with Adobe Illustrator

Tags: css, svg, adobe-illustrator

I am using Adobe Illustrator to create SVG images. 
I need to set some additional attributes to the elements in the SVG, for example the CSS `class` attribute. I would even like to add attribute from a custom namespace to it.

How is this possible? The attributes from a custom namespace are "nice to have", but the `class` attribute is a MUST.

Comment: Not sure why this is closed. It is common to do front-end development with custom SVG code, and it is also common to create/edit SVGs in Illustrator. Other than the fact that the question is 2 years old now, I think it should be reopened

Comment: Why off topic? I'm using Inkscape as SVG IDE to develop JavaScript applications that uses SVG. I have a lot of issues with Inkscape on Mac and I'm trying to know if Illustrator can help me... and this entry brings me hope :)

Comment: I have the same question, and I'm using AI created SVGs in my JS application too. What's the rationale behind closing it, other than that it has to do with a drawing tool?

Comment: The best way to add a class to your SVG in Illustrator is by using graphic styles. Hope that helps someone!

Comment: Just another useful question that is closed.

Comment: This question appears high in many relevant search results. Closing it feels like designophobia, and is inexplicable while this question remains: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236365/optimal-settings-for-exporting-svgs-for-the-web-from-illustrator

Comment: More constructively, the end of this article contains a possible answer that works (with caveats) as of CC 2015: http://creativedroplets.com/export-svg-for-the-web-with-illustrator-cc/

Answer (score 1):

I have not found a method for doing this with Adobe Illustrator, but it is very easy with Inkscape. Use the XML Editor (Edit » XML Editor) hack your attribute with namespace then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and it will be in the XML.