# What are the specifications for svg files when using FontCustom

Tags: css, web, svg, webfonts, woff

So I'm using FontCustom to make my own set of web fonts from a set of vector graphics from our design department. All is going well except that one of my icons is the company logo and it's designed in a 2:1 aspect ratio. (400px by 200px).

Technically FontCustom is making my font package and it's technically working on my site, but my problem is the the svg file that it makes has my company logo in a 1:1 aspect ratio, and I have a log of blank space below my glyph.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Do I need to pass some specific instructions to the FontCustom compiler?

Thanks

Comment: Excellent answer here [Optimal settings for exporting SVGs for the web from Illustrator][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236365/optimal-settings-for-exporting-svgs-for-the-web-from-illustrator